# Android studio 1.4 and VCS (git) can not commit code

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Yesterday I updated `IDE Android Studio` upgrade to version 1.4 but something went wrong as below:
My team are using `Android Studio` with `Git` and `Bitbucket` for working.
When I try to commit my changes, `Android studio` was stuck as image.

I was try to deleted old one and Download new one but after some success commitment this issue happens again.

When I click to commit my changes
[image]

After click, `Android studio` was stuck as image and no response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Unticking the "Perform Code Analysis" option at the right pane, resolved the problem.